# launching parser script once in 24 hours

Tags: 6

I have a file parser.php

```
$url = 'http://site.kz';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/5.0 ");
curl_setopt ($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 );
$link = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

so all contents of the site -site.kz is in $content variable. If i call this script http://site.kz/sites/all/themes/mytheme/parser.php -> it starts to grab this page, right?

How can i make available that variable $link in a page.tpl.php? If i make `include ('parser.php')` then everytime i F5 my page → parser is going to work (creates load to the server).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your script to execute on each page load, you have to set up a cron job, either via [hook_cron()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_cron/6) or a separate job.

To make a variable available in a template file, you have to use a [preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/6) function of some sort.

With these two elements, you should be able to make your script work and be integrated with Drupal.

Comment: can u throw examples?

Comment: I could but don't have time, sorry. Could do it as a paid job though o_O. You'll find plenty of examples on d.o or many other places.